# java snake game (with circles)

Tags: java

I am trying to make a snake game in java but the thing i am trying to make is not a normal snake game. I want to make a snake game which is snake (player) can go to every direction (like in slither.io game). 
And i am trying to make a snake from circles.

[image: This is how snake is supposed to look and move]

I am trying to use `Graphics2D` for it and I successfully draw a circle.
But I couldnt make it lot of circles which is attached to eachothers. (I tryed to use `arrayList`).

---

Also like in classical snake game i want to make snake grow when it eats food.
But instead of making it longer i need to add more circles.

[image: Snake Growing]

Code i wrote for the circle (script name is also "Circle");

```
    public void drawToScreen(Graphics2D g) 
    {
        g.setColor(GameConstants.BORDER_COLOR);
        BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(5);
        g.setStroke(stroke);
        Ellipse2D border = new Ellipse2D.Double(getX()-getSize()/2, getY()-getSize()/2, getSize(), getSize());
        g.draw(border);

        g.setColor(getColor());
        Ellipse2D shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(getX()-getSize()/2, getY()-getSize()/2, getSize(), getSize());
        g.fill(shape);

        setBounds(shape.getBounds());

        // Here is for the username
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        int width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(getName());
        g.drawString(getName(), (int)(getX()-width/2), (int)(getY()+5));
    }
```

I have another script ("`GamePanel`") which I set up game, in that script I call some function whit this codes.

```
private Circle player;
```

---

```
player = new Circle(GameConstants.START_SIZE, spawnPoint.getX(), spawnPoint.getY(), randomColor(), GameConstants.START_VELOCITY, name);
```

---

```
player.drawToScreen(g2);        
g2.translate(viewX, viewY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have zero clue what a "Script" is in Java.

But here is the source code to a game with very similar aspects that you can draw lessons from.

I made the Enemy ai a tad to intelligent, but you you will see how to do what you are asking in this code.

[The Great Escape](http://www.jeremiahstillings.net/programming/The%20Great%20Escape/jstillingsproject.zip)

Comment: Yes thank you, its very similar to what i want to do. I tryed to implement it to do my code and i archived to create lot of circles. But they all nested. How can i make them little bir far from each others so it can look like a snake.

Comment: That is a tricky question and will be based on the direction that your snake is moving in currently.  You can take the snakes head x and y center and based on this direction it is moving  figure out where the other body parts needs to be drawn